# Using with ... as statements vs simply declaring variables

Tags: python

I just started learning python via Jupyter.

What's the difference between code 1 and code 2?

1. Using `with`:

   ```
   with open('myfile.txt') as new_file:
       contents = new_file.read()
   ```
2. Without using `with`:

   ```
   new_file = open('myfile.txt')
   contents = new_file.read()
   ```

Can I use code 2 always? It's more straightforward than code 1.

Comment: No, you're leaking the file handle in the second case, which is why the first exists. The context manager will close the handle for you.

Comment: Damn that was quick. Thanks for formatting the post. First time for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the first case you're using what's called a context manager - i.e. when the `with` block is finished, the file will also be closed afterwards (since it's no longer needed after the `with` block has finished executing).

This means that the two pieces of code doesn't do the same - instead, you'd have to also remember to close the file after reading it in the latter case:

```
new_file = open('myfile.txt')
contents = new_file.read()
new_file.close()
```

In addition, an exception might happen which the code that wraps your code uses, so in that case you have to make sure to close it even if an exception occurs:

```py
new_file = open('myfile.txt')

try:
    contents = new_file.read()
finally:
    new_file.close()
```

And instead of doing this manually, you can let Python handle it automagically by you as the file handle itself can be context manager:

```py
with open('myfile.txt') as new_file:
    contents = new_file.read()
```

No more manually thinking about when to close the file and how to handle any potential alternative flows.

Answer (score 2):

Ironically, in your second snippet you forgot to `close(new_file)`, *which is exactly why `with` exists*.

It's really no more straightforward, but that doesn't even matter, because it's *wrong*.

Answer (score 0):

For the first case: You don't need to explicitly call the close() method. It is done internally.

As for the second you should explicitly call the close() method.